# How to send GET request from remote host using SSH connection in Python?

Tags: python, api, flask

How to send GET request from connected remote host .
I tried it through CMD. First I login to the ssh root, then send this request:

```
curl -X GET "https://bsms.its.com.pk/otpsms.php?key=xxxxx&receiver=xxx&sender=xxxx&param1=uxxser&otpcode=1234"
```

It works. Same thing I am trying to do in my python flask but it doesn't work.

```
username = 'root'
hostname = '175.111.0.26'
port = 22
password='passowrd'


def do_it():
    s = paramiko.SSHClient()
    s.load_system_host_keys()
    s.connect(hostname, port, username, password)
    command = "https://bsms.its.com.pk/otpsms.php?key=xxx&receiver=number&sender=xxxx&param1=xxx&otpcode=1234"
    command.request("GET", '/')
    s.exec_command(command)
    print(command)
   
    s.close()
```

Comment: Literally pass the string you have there as your curl command into exec_command. Why are you putting only the url there and then try to access a property on it that certainly does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

What about this ?

```html
# Connect to the remote host
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.connect(hostname, username=username, password=password)

# Send the GET request using the `curl` command
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('curl ' + url)

# Print the response
print(stdout.read())

# Close the connection
client.close()
```